# Warning: Resource leak: 'keyboard' is never closed

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterGrade {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char grade;
    String input;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter grade awarded");

    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    grade = input.charAt(0);

    switch (grade) {
      case 'A':
        System.out.println("Grade was between 89.5 and 100");
        break;  
      case 'B':
        System.out.println("Grade was between 79.5 and 89.49"); 
        break;  
      case 'C':
        System.out.println("Grade was between 69.5 and 79.49");
        break; 
      case 'D':
        System.out.println("Grade was between 59.5 and 69.49");
        break;
      case 'F':
        System.out.println("Grade was below 59.5");
        break;
      default:
        System.out.println("Invalid grade inputted");
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

> [line: 9] Warning: Resource leak: 'keyboard' is never closed

That's the warning that I'm receiving. I don't think the source is actually being leaked.
But i don't know how to get it off so i can compile the code

Answer (score 7):

It is safe to ignore that warning, and I would never `close()` a scanner that is wrapping the global `System.in`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you never close it?

Comment: @Abbath Because once `System.in` is closed, you'll need to restart your program to get it open again. If you `close()` immediately before `exit()` it's fine, but if you extract this into a method it can cause you all kinds of grief as your program *mysteriously* stops accepting input.

Answer (score 5):

You need to close the keyboard Scanner.
`keyboard.close()`.

Comment: Where do i add it? I added it at the end of the code and i got a new error.

Comment: When you are no longer using it, i.e after the switch statement.

Comment: @AjayP: Place it after the `input` assignment or after the `switch` block. Please acknowledge the usefulness of SCOPE.

Answer (score 1):

You opened the keyboard with:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This needs to be closed with the `keyboard.close()` method when the keyboard input is no longer needed.